# Best book about ROS with Python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there are lots of online resources but I am looking for a book (online or paper) which has the concepts and lots of examples of using ROS with Python. (The book called "ROS with Python isn't really about that at all). I also know about http://wiki.ros.org/Books but those are all self-promoted. Can anyone recommend a book they liked? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268572/best-book-about-ros-with-python/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-08-11**:
You should look at *Programming Robots with ROS: A Practical Introduction to the Robot Operating System / Edition 1*. That's a great one, with [examples](https://github.com/osrf/rosbook).

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-08-11**:
Yes I am familiar with it, and I agree with you. I was looking if there were other key ones that I hadn't picked up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a tough one to answer as it's highly subjective. But here's my go.

I think that you're going to find that there really aren't any *great* books available for ROS and Python<del>, or really ROS in general</del> (as @gvdhoorn pointed out in the comments, there are great books for ROS, I just hadn't found them). Most books (for ROS and Python) just seem to skim over the basics, reiterate the tutorials, or introduce more "advanced" concepts but in a manner without much depth (IMHO).

I've read Programming Robots with ROS: A Practical Introduction to the Robot Operating System, ROS Robotics By Example, A Gentle Introduction to ROS (C++), and a couple others that I can't recall.

Every time I read a book about ROS (and Python) I feel like I'm basically just going through the tutorials in a slightly different way. This can be great if you're new and looking to reinforce the basics but not helpful if you're trying to use ROS (and Python) professionally. However, the two "best" books about ROS (and Python) that I've found are the [ROS by Example INDIGO Volumes 1 and 2 by R. Patrick Goebel](http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/pirobot).

There are some really great examples using SMACH, behavior trees, muxing, using the nav stack, etc.

Note: Now, this isn't to disparage the authors of the books, but rather just an observation that I've made on my own. I think that part of the reason is that ROS is very large with a huge ecosystem. Couple that with the different programming languages in use with ROS and the sheer number of its capabilities and that makes it difficult to write an in-depth book without making a giant tome.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-08-11**:
I agree with you. And it's such a broad system, the whole ROS ecosystem. And while there are a lot of tutorials and wiki pages still overall it's not well documented at all. Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:
I don't know about Python, but I don't agree with the general idea of "there are no good ROS books".

Please take a look at *ROS: The Complete Reference* [vol1](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319260525) and [vol2](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319549262).

They might be expensive ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:
.. but I think you'll find it hard to maintain the "it's basically the tutorials, rehashed" with these books.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-08-12**:
@gvdhoorn They look good, but wow, for that price I could BUY a turtlebot3 (almost?!) I would definitely want to preview them before spending the money.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-12**:
To be fair, I didn't say "there are no good ROS books." Except for the books I mentioned, I hadn't found books that get you beyond the basics with ROS *and Python*. I've found that reading the source code of ROS and others' packages to be more beneficial (and economical).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:\

> I think that you're going to find that there really aren't any great books available for ROS and Python, or really ROS in general

?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:\

> I've found that reading the source code of ROS and others' packages to be more beneficial (and economical)

this I do agree with, but is probably very much subjective. Some people just prefer to have a book that guides them.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:
@pitosalas: yes, they are rather expensive unfortunately :(

I don't really understand why either.

> I would definitely want to preview them before spending the money.

you get 2 page previews per chapter.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-08-12**:
By the way, I've looked at ROS by Example INDIGO Volumes 1 by R. Patrick Goebel and it is indeed excellent!

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-13**:
The *ROS: The Complete Reference* books are expensive because they're not actually books. They're just a collection of unrelated research papers that has been compiled by Springer. Since each 'book' essentially has 40+ authors, they need to charge a premium for it to be worth it at all.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-13**:
To be honest also, I've got access to both volumes of *ROS: The Complete Reference* and I highly recommend not bothering with them, unless there is a chapter that pertains exactly to what you're working on. All the topics are fairly specialized, and they mostly use ROS as a framework to explain...

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-13**:
... their research topics, rather than being books devoted to helping you *understand* ROS itself. The exceptions would be the papers on the MoveIt Introduction and the Navigation Tutorial in Volume 1. I'd only look at the rest if it's highly relatable to your project.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-14**:\

> They're just a collection of unrelated research papers that has been compiled by Springer. Since each 'book' essentially has 40+ authors, they need to charge a premium for it to be worth it at all.

Which still doesn't explain why they have to be $150+ each. But that is for another discussion.